# How to override Foreground for selected ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

I have a global style (Application.Resources) to set the Foreground of all TextBlocks.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Brown"/>
</Style>
```

This works fine.

Now I try to override the Foreground of the TextBlock inside of a selected ListBoxItem, which is part of default ContentPresenter content.

I created a new global style for the ListBoxItem:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Aqua" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The background works fine.

But Foreground has still the brush form de global style from the TextBlock.
Which is the best way to set the Foreground in a solution that works with Binding?

Comment: If you want to *"override the Foreground of the TextBlock inside of a selected ListBoxItem"* why don't you put a TextBlock inside the Template, instead of a ContentPresenter?

Comment: That was also my first idea. But, what would be bound then? 
<TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{???}"/>

Comment: `Text="{Binding}"` if the items are strings or the item class has an appropriate ToString method. Otherwise bind to some property of the item class.

Comment: Yes, but if I bind it with `Text="{Binding}"` then I lose the `DisplayMemberPath`-Feature. And if I bind it to a specific Property of the Model, I need a specific Template (Style) for each Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of why defining an implicit application-wide `TextBlock` style is usually a bad idea.

But you should be able to override it by adding a default style to to `<ContentPresenter.Resources>`:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" />
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```